# Changing duration of UIviewController transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, core-animation, catransaction

I am using this code to change between one view controller to another:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerWoodenPage3"];

[UIView  beginAnimations:@"ShowAnswers" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.4];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: lvc animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The code works fine, but it seems that the duration of the animation is not taken in consideration. it is always very fast, whatever value I insert.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723545/use-of-beginanimations-discouraged

I think beginAnimations is discouraged from 4.0 from the question.

Comment: You're not doing anything here in terms of animation. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: slow down the push of the view controller from the standard 0.3 secs to 0.7f secs

Comment: Lots of answers provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app