# About 'beginAnimations' and 'commitAnimations'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added in the button click event:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
sender.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The animation is not working. But if I remove `[UIView commitAnimations];`, the animation works. Why?
If I don't add `[UIView commitAnimations];`, what will happen?

Comment: Those methods are deprecated. Use the block-based version of `UIView` animations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723545/use-of-beginanimations-discouraged

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but '[UIView animateWithDuration: <# (NSTimeInterval) #> animations: <# ^ (void) animations #> completion: <# ^ (BOOL finished) completion #>]' Also does not work

Comment: `UILabel font` is not an animatable property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494566/animating-uilabel-font-size-change?s=1|1.6166

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply,My problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are not using this for view animations?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // place your animations code here
}];
```

Note: please visit this url and see the section **What can be animated**. Only few properties can be used for animations

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

Try this, it will help. In the example below, viewObject may be label in your case.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    viewObject.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
}];
```